# CSS + link rollover = display image (unique URL)

Tags: css, image, rollover

I am curious as the best (only?) way to go about this.

I was asked to make a text link, display an image (under it) upon rollover and of course disappear when you rolloff the link.

(the original personal used some in-line style that broke the page, instead of declaring a block).. they also tried to use an IMAGE MAP to make the displayed image a LINK/clickable, and have a different/unique URL that the TEXT link used to display the image.

I made the style:

```
/*custom client requested CSS styling/functionality*/
a.imageDisplay img { 
    display:none; 
}
a.imageDisplay:hover img { 
    display:block; 
}
```

Here is a snippet of the HTML I am try to add this functionality to:

```
<a class="imageDisplay" href="#">Client Name XYZ<img src="/UserFiles/image/ALLSAtestpage3.jpg" usemap="#allsa" /><map id="allsa" name="allsa"><area coords="12,113,123,142" href="http://www.nike.com/" shape="rect" target="_blank" /></map></a><br />
```

My question is: what is the best way (better way) to add a LINK/URL to the image that is being displayed?

Because the image is INSIDE the anchor/link tag.. is will also be/get the same URL as the target when clicked....yes?

Anybody have some SIMPLE ideas as a work around?

(I really hate those MAP tags anyways) :)

thanks!

Comment: put the image outside the link maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this simple?

```
<span class="txt-img">
    <a class="txt" href="#1">Client Name ABC</a>
    <a class="img" href="#2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200/0000cc/" /></a>
</span>

.txt-img {position:relative;}
.txt-img .img {position:absolute; display:none; left:0;}
.txt-img:hover .img {display:block;}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/46Tf6/

Comment: Thanks for the reply...

Maybe I wasnt clear (sorry) but how would this work for MANY links on the page trying to do the same thing though?  say 10 links..each one on hover, needs to display an 'image' (section/block/div) under that link being hovered over (pushing other links down if needed..etc)  this would affect (trigger) all links.....no? Is there is a way in CSS to target the current element?  (like jQuery $this for example?)

Thanks

Comment: Anybody?  no work-around without using jQuery?  (as the above code would affect/trigger ALL hidden DIV/content when ANY link was rolled over.. correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle?  It does not trigger ALL hidden content, just the hidden content inside the span that is being hovered.

Comment: I just checked 'fiddle' (new to that)..  thanks!  And it does seem to do what I originally intended.  Thanks!  (How do I mark as answer? says I need 15 rep points to up-vote?)

Comment: Hi - I am finally trying to work your solution into my project..
But Im having 1 issue, it seems as if it is NOT pushing the rest of the content DOWN, and is instead overlaying it above the rest of the content?
 
Example code:
    .associationLinks {
  position:relative;
  font-size:11px
 }
 .associationLinks .content {
  position:absolute; 
  display:none; 
  left:0;
 }
 .associationLinks:hover .content {
  display:block;
 }

    $stringTemplate= '<div class="associationLinks">
     <a class="link" href="#">{ContentTitle}</a>
     <img class="content" src="{Content}"/>
     </div>';

Comment: Hi - I am finally trying to work your solution into my project..
But Im having 1 issue, it seems as if it is NOT pushing the rest of the content DOWN, and is instead overlaying it above the rest of the content?
 
Example code:
    .associationLinks {
  position:relative;
  font-size:11px
 }
 .associationLinks .content {
  position:absolute; 
  display:none; 
  left:0;
 }
 .associationLinks:hover .content {
  display:block;
 }

    $stringTemplate= '<div class="associationLinks">
     <a class="link" href="#">{ContentTitle}</a>
     <img class="content" src="{Content}"/>
     </div>';

Comment: just saw your comment now.  I intended the image to overlay the rest of the content; I thought that was what you wanted.  Pushing the rest of the content down really depends on your specific page HTML and it probably won't look good.  Create a fiddle if you want more help.